# Do I need to delete a boost thread that I created?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am creating a thread like this:

```
 MyThread = new boost::thread(&MyThreadFunction, this);
```

and MyThreadFunction is:

```
void MyThreadFunction()
{
    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
        cout<< "Test"<<i<<endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see the thread is fishes after some times (or when it is interrupted.) So I need to create a new thread when I need to run MyThreadFunction.

Do I need to delete the thread?

How can I check if the thread still running so I can not delete it when running?

Comment: Yes. But don't allocate it with `new`.

Comment: Always delete something that is created with new.

Comment: @juanchopanza so how to create it?

Comment: It depends on where and how you are allocating. There is not enough information to know for sure.

Comment: @juanchopanza You said don't allocate it with new, is there any other way to allocate it?

Comment: Of course. What I would call "the normal way", in automatic storage, i.e. without `new`. You need strong reasons to use `new`, not the other way around.

Comment: Note that there is a distinction between the thread and the C++ object representing the thread. Hence creating a local C++ object doesn't cause the thread to be terminated or otherwise destroyed when that object is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

The first question you need to answer is "What is the lifecycle of the thread?"

Is the thread's lifecycle bounded by some higher-level function?  If so, you need to determine a policy for joining the child thread.  After the thread is joined, you can (and must) safely delete the dynamically allocated thread.  If you don't delete the thread, you'll have all the usual memory loss associated with boost::thread object itself (rather than resource loss from not joining the underlying Posix/Windows/etc. thread)

If the thread's lifecycle is NOT bounded by a higher-level function, just create the thread and call detach on it.  At this point "the boost::thread object ceases to represent the now-detached thread" (see reference) and you can safely delete the boost::thread object.  There's no need to keep track or hold onto the boost::thread pointer.  The underlying OS thread resource will be cleaned up at program termination.

Of course, in most cases, there isn't any need for dynamically allocating boost::thread objects in the first place.  If you need to control the lifecycle and join them later, it's probably best to have a class that maintains ownership of the thread and treats it as a class member.

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.detach